# Error: incorrect data check at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17)

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, hadoop-yarn

Im trying to yarn install my local repo and getting the below error in terminal
`Error: incorrect data check at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17)`
This is my machine configuration
macOS Sonoma (intel chip) MacBook Pro
node v16.20.1
npm 8.19.4
yarn 1.22.21

As far the only difference I see is int this issue is happening after OS upgrade in my machine Previously I was using Monterey.

I could not find any useful resource to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got solved after I downgrade my OS to previous version which is Monterey. Lol this issue is only postponed till my company mandates everyone to update macOS